# Create a new website under Default website of IIS in installshield 2009 pro

Tags: installshield-2009

I'm using InstallShield2009 pro to create my website installer. I want to create a new Website under DefaultWebsite in IIS. I haven't found any option to do that in Installshield 2009.

Do you have some solution to accomplish this task?

Comment: Oh I found a solution. Tks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just select a port and another Site Number to do this task!